# Finding the second lowest frequent element from an array of integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frequency

**I'm looking to answer a coding challenge in JavaScript that I'm stuck on, here's the question:**

Write a function which accepts an array of integers and returns an element of that array.

The function should determine the frequency of each element (how many times the element appears in the array) and whenever possible should return the element with the second-lowest frequency. Otherwise it should return the integer with the lowest frequency.

If there is more than one element satisfying the requirements then the second smallest one (according to value) should be returned.

Example outputs:

secondLowest( [4, 3, 1, 1, 2] ) === 1

secondLowest( [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2] ) === 2

secondLowest( [4, 3, 1, 2] ) === 2

**This is what I've got so far although don't know how best to go about answering it after this:**

```
    function mode(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) return null;
  let modeMap = {};
  let maxEl = array[0],
    maxCount = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var el = array[i];
    if (modeMap[el] == null) modeMap[el] = 1;
    else modeMap[el]++;
    if (modeMap[el] > maxCount) {
      maxEl = el;
      maxCount = modeMap[el];
    }
  }
  return maxEl;
}
```

Comment: *challenge* ... please add yours.

Comment: The first example should return 2, not one, right?

Comment: Either the first example should return 2, or the second example should return 1...

Comment: @MHebes It returns 1 as it says "whenever possible should return the element with the second-lowest frequency" as 1 appears twice on that occasion and the rest once (it's not worded great so apologies)

Comment: In the second example 1 also appears twice, but the result is supposedly 2. In order for this to be a valid question, you should also show your own attempt at coding a solution.

Comment: @Gershom Hi, I believe that's because it says if there is more than one element satisfying the requirements then the second smallest value should be returned - so as there are two 1's and two 2's, return the second smallest of the two numbers

Comment: @Gershom thanks, I'll add where I've got to so far with it

Comment: Ok, that helps clarify! Ideally the second highest frequency, and in case of a tie, the second highest value. You actually explained this reasonably well, I just didn't read carefully.

Comment: Hey @Asher! Welcome to StackOverflow :) 

@Gershom is correct; It is customary when posting a question to show the work you've already tried, so those answering can zero in on where you're having trouble and provide assistance quickly. It is asking a lot of an answerer to solve your problem completely from scratch on your behalf.

Comment: @Gershom Thank you!

Comment: @WillBuck Thanks Will, appreciate the heads up and noted for next time! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was determined to give a generic, parameterized function, where no number is hardcoded.

Your example involved two hardcoded values:

- The *second least* frequency should be selected
- In cases of ties, the *second least* value should be selected

The following code works like this:

- Get the frequency of each input value
- Group together all values with the same frequency.
- Sort these grouped pairs by frequency and select the nth-lowest (in your case, `n=2`)
- If the nth-lowest frequency has multiple pairs, sort these pairs by *value*, and select the mth-lowest pair (in your case, `m=2`)
- Return the value of this final pair

The `m` and `n` parameters I refer to here are called `freqInd` and `valInd` in the code. Note that in order to select the second-lowest frequency, `freqInd` should be `1`, not `2` (since `0` would select the lowest, and therefore `1` selects the second-lowest).

```js
let lowestFreqVal = (freqInd, valInd, values) => {
  
  // Calculate frequencies in a map
  let f = new Map();
  for (let v of values) f.set(v, (f.get(v) || 0) + 1);
  
  // Group together all val/freq pairs with the same frequency
  let ff = new Map();
  for (let [ val, freq ] of f) ff.set(freq, (ff.get(freq) || []).concat([ val ]));
  
  // Sort these groups by frequency
  let byFreq = [ ...ff ].sort(([ freq1 ], [ freq2 ]) => freq1 - freq2);  
  
  // Here are all the items of the `freqInd`-th lowest frequency, sorted by value
  // Note that `[1]` returns an array of integers at the frequency, whereas `[0]` would return the frequency itself
  let lowestItems = byFreq[ Math.min(byFreq.length - 1, freqInd) ][1]
    .sort((v1, v2) => v1 - v2);
  
  // Return the `valInd`-th lowest value
  return lowestItems[ Math.min(lowestItems.length - 1, valInd) ];
  
};

console.log('Some random examples:');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // An array of random length, full of random integers
  let arr = [ ...new Array(3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) ]
    .map(v => Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
  
  // Show the result of `lowestFreqVal` on this random Array
  console.log(`lowestFreqVal(1, 1, ${JSON.stringify(arr)}) = ${lowestFreqVal(1, 1, arr)}`);
}
```

This is not an optimal solution, since it resorts to using `sort`. It's known that the problem of finding some nth-maximal value in a list can be implemented to have a better runtime than `sort` (and a significantly better runtime when `n` is a small value - we can see this intuitively because if `n=0`, a single pass (`O(n)`) does the trick).

Comment: Thanks for this! Very helpful, I still find the code quite hard to understand but will keep going through it and the explanation is in great depth. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks you so much once again! Much appreciated